# how to insert an old timestamp in updated_at column in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table in postgres which has a column named `updated_at`. Will this column always auto-update? Is it possible to insert an older timestamp in this column or will it only default to the time when the query runs? (say the query runs at 3:15 pm; can I insert the timestamp of 3:10 pm in updated_at column?)

I am using Rails application; so I would like to insert an old timestamp using my Rails code (not sure if this is relevant to my question but wanted to clarify anyway)

Comment: This depends on how the column is filled. Is there a DEFAULT value? Is there a UPDATE trigger? Is there nothing? To answer correctly we need to know about your structure.

Comment: There is no update trigger. There  is no default value. I am just trying to insert one record from my Rails code; I am able to insert values for all fields but `updated_at` seems to always have only the time when the SQL runs and not the time I try to insert in my code.

Comment: What is the difference between these two timestamps? When you are inserting something into your table, a SQL query is called...

Comment: The query ran at 3:15 pm, but I tried to insert the timestamp of 3:10 pm in the column updated_at; after the SQL ran, updated_at contains 3:15 pm and not the value which I inserted (3:10 pm)

Comment: Show us your query please

Comment: You might want to try looking at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+updated_at).

Comment: @jvillian - that was very helpful. thanks! Is there a way to avoid record_timestamps only for updated_at and not created_at?

Answer (score 0):

This case you should use [updated_at](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns) method from ActiveRecord::Persistence, that will prevent update_at from being updated:

```
user.update_columns(updated_at: Time.current)
```